# Help me to optimize this query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Please suggest indexes to optimize below query. I couldn't allowed to rewrite the query but create indexes:

```
SELECT 
    `ADV`.`inds` as `c0`, 
    sum(`ADVpost`.`clk`) as `m0`
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM advts
     WHERE comp_id = 
        (SELECT comp_id 
         FROM comp 
         WHERE name = 'abc'))  as `ADV`, 
        (SELECT dt_id,
                comp_id,
                b_id,
                ad_id,
                clk,
                resp
         FROM advts_post
         WHERE comp_id = 
                 (SELECT comp_id 
                  FROM comp 
                  WHERE name = 'abc')) as `ADVpost`
WHERE 
    `ADVpost`.`ad_id` = `ADV`.`ad_id`
GROUP BY 
    `ADV`.`inds`
ORDER BY 
    ISNULL(`ADV`.`inds`), `ADV`.`inds` ASC
```

The explain for the query is as:

```
select_type table       type    possible_keys   Extra
PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     null            Using temporary; Using filesort
PRIMARY     <derived4>  ALL     null            Using where; Using join buffer
DERIVED     ADVpost     ALL     null            Using where
SUBQUERY    comp        ALL     null            Using where
DERIVED     advts       ALL     null            Using where
SUBQUERY    comp        ALL     null            Using where
```

Existing indexes are as follows:

```
ADVpost > PRIMARY KEY (`dt_id`,`comp_id`,`b_id`,`ad_id`)

comp    > PRIMARY KEY (`comp_id`)

advts   > PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the nested queries are unnecessary, a couple of JOINS with indexes on `comp.name`, `advts.comp_id`, `advts_post.comp_id`, `advts_post.ad_id` and `advts.inds` should suffice.

Comment: @Orbling plus index on `advts_post.ad_id`, if I read the query correctly.

Comment: @Tadeck: I think you mean `advts.ad_id` (as I have the other listed).  I deliberately left that off, as it is listed as a pre-existing `PRIMARY`.

Comment: @Orbling Yes, you have it (`advts_post.ad_id`) listed now.

Comment: Indexes on comp.name, advts.comp_id, advts_post.comp_id, advts_post.ad_id and advts.inds did not help at all friends. Any further suggestions. I am sorry to say but I can not modify the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query is a dogs dinner - whoever wrote it should be severely punished, and the person who said you can't rewrite it but must make it run faster should be shot.

Loose the sub-selects!

MySQL does not do push-predicates very well (at all?).

Use proper joins instead and state implied joins:

```
SELECT ap.inds, SUM(ap.clk)
FROM advts_post AS ap
, comp AS co
, advts ad
WHERE ap.comp_id = co.comp_id
AND ad.comp_id = co.comp_id
AND ap.comp_id = ad.comp_id
AND co.name='abc'
GROUP BY ap.inds
ORDER BY ISNULL(ap.inds), ap.inds ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, maybe I am not an expert with MySQL optimization, but:

- if it is possible and reasonable, try to avoid subselects where possible (instead it may be better to make separate query and then pass the retrieved ID, like `comp_id`, to the containing query),
- put index on `comp.name`,
- put index on `advts_post.comp_id` (single one),
- put index on `advts_post.ad_id` (single one),

Maybe it is rather simple, but should help at least slightly make it faster. Tell us about the results.

Comment: Sorry but those indexes did not help.